# SSRS 2005, IE7 & Matrix. Very wide column

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-7

When showing a report on Report Server 2005 in IE7 (I know it would be nice to upgrade but its not possible) the matrix columns (dynamic) are shown really wide (e.g. 753505px!)

Looking at the source the data is actually being populated in the cells, just out of view by a few thousand pixels.

Viewing in Firefox or IE10 after changing compatibility views renders the report correctly but in a small box.

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image: matrix report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In the column headers I had set the writing mode to tb-rl (vertical text). By setting this back to the default (lr-tb) the problem was fixed.